# The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'method' in type 'service' is invalid. in wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

I am trying to make a `WCF` service in visual studio as you can see here:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IReportSRC{

           [OperationContract]
        List<tblArticle> ReturnArticleList();

        [OperationContract]
       int ReturnArticleListCount();

         [OperationContract]
        List<tblPayment> ReturnPaymentList();

         [OperationContract]
         int ReturnPaymentSum();

         [OperationContract]
        List<tblNew> ReturnNews();

         [OperationContract]
        List<tblUserInfo> ReturnUsers();

         [OperationContract]
        int ReturnUsersCount();

         [OperationContract]
        List<tblUserInfo> ReturnReviewers();

         [OperationContract]
        List<tblSponsor> ReturnsSponser();

    }
```

So i implement this Interface as you can see in my service :

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
        RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ReportSRC : IReportSRC
    {
        dblinqtoDb.dbDataContext db=new dbDataContext();


        List<tblArticle> IReportSRC.ReturnArticleList()
        {
            return db.tblArticles.ToList();
        }

        public List<tblPayment> ReturnPaymentList()
        {
            return db.tblPayments.ToList();
        }

        public List<tblNew> ReturnNews()
        {
            return db.tblNews.ToList();
        }
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        public List<tblUserInfo> ReturnUsers()
        {
            return db.tblUserInfos.ToList();
        }

        public List<tblUserInfo> ReturnReviewers()
        {
            List<tblUserInfo> res =
                (from i in db.tblUserInfos
                 join b in db.tblUserLogins on i.Username equals b.Username
                 where b.IsJuror == "1"
                 select i).ToList();
            return res;

        }

        public List<tblSponsor> ReturnsSponser()
        {
            return db.tblSponsors.ToList();

        }


        public int ReturnArticleListCount()
        {
            return db.tblArticles.Count();
        }

        public int ReturnPaymentSum()
        {
            return db.tblPayments.Sum(i => int.Parse(i.Price));
        }

        public int ReturnUsersCount()
        {
            return db.tblUserInfos.Count();
        }
    }
```

So i call  my service in my local computer `http://localhost:2432/services/reportsrc.svc` ,but when i call the service i get this error :

```
The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'ReturnUsers' in type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' is invalid. OperationContractAttributes are only valid on methods that are declared in a type that has ServiceContractAttribute. Either add ServiceContractAttribute to type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' or remove OperationContractAttribute from method 'ReturnUsers'.
```

When i run just the service with the visual wizard:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:2432/Services/ReportSRC.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:2432/Services/ReportSRC.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:2432/Services/ReportSRC.svc'.    The requested service, 'http://localhost:2432/Services/ReportSRC.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:2432/Services/ReportSRC.svc    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:2432/Services/ReportSRC.svc'.    The request failed with the error message:--<!DOCTYPE html><html>    <head>        <title>The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'ReturnUsers' in type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' is invalid. OperationContractAttributes are only valid on methods that are declared in a type that has ServiceContractAttribute. Either add ServiceContractAttribute to type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' or remove OperationContractAttribute from method 'ReturnUsers'.</title>        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />        <style>         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}         .version {color: gray;}         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }         }         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {          pre { width: 280px; }         }        </style>    </head>    <body bgcolor="white">            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>            <h2> <i>The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'ReturnUsers' in type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' is invalid. OperationContractAttributes are only valid on methods that are declared in a type that has ServiceContractAttribute. Either add ServiceContractAttribute to type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' or remove OperationContractAttribute from method 'ReturnUsers'.</i> </h2></span>            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.            <br><br>            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'ReturnUsers' in type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' is invalid. OperationContractAttributes are only valid on methods that are declared in a type that has ServiceContractAttribute. Either add ServiceContractAttribute to type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' or remove OperationContractAttribute from method 'ReturnUsers'.<br><br>            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">               <tr>                  <td>                      <code>An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>                  </td>               </tr>            </table>            <br>            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">               <tr>                  <td>                      <code><pre>[InvalidOperationException: The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'ReturnUsers' in type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' is invalid. OperationContractAttributes are only valid on methods that are declared in a type that has ServiceContractAttribute. Either add ServiceContractAttribute to type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' or remove OperationContractAttribute from method 'ReturnUsers'.]   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceReflector.GetInterfaces(Type service) +471   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts) +248   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +146   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +46   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +146   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +30   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +494   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1434   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Services/ReportSRC.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'ReturnUsers' in type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' is invalid. OperationContractAttributes are only valid on methods that are declared in a type that has ServiceContractAttribute. Either add ServiceContractAttribute to type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' or remove OperationContractAttribute from method 'ReturnUsers'..]   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +489276   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +73   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest() +461   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129</pre></code>                  </td>               </tr>            </table>            <br>            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>            <b>Version Information:</b>ÿMicrosoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34280            </font>    </body></html><!-- [InvalidOperationException]: The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'ReturnUsers' in type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' is invalid. OperationContractAttributes are only valid on methods that are declared in a type that has ServiceContractAttribute. Either add ServiceContractAttribute to type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' or remove OperationContractAttribute from method 'ReturnUsers'.   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceReflector.GetInterfaces(Type service)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)[ServiceActivationException]: The service '/Services/ReportSRC.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'ReturnUsers' in type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' is invalid. OperationContractAttributes are only valid on methods that are declared in a type that has ServiceContractAttribute. Either add ServiceContractAttribute to type 'AccidentCongress.Services.ReportSRC' or remove OperationContractAttribute from method 'ReturnUsers'..   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)-->--.
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the code which is actually being compiled, it looks okay to me.

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars yes  it compiled .

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars i add some information to my post,could you please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line of code in implementation layer of interface :

```
 [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
```

When i remove this line everything works fine .but i don't know why?

Comment: The error message was pretty clear as to why it wasn't working the way you had it:  "OperationContractAttributes are only valid on methods that are declared in a type that has ServiceContractAttribute."  In other words, `ReportSRC` (the type) wasn't marked with the `[ServiceContractAttribute]`, so it's methods couldn't be marked with `[OperationContractAttribute]`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to specify operation contract in implementation class?
You can specify in interface with one way attribute like below and it will work fine.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
List<tblUserInfo> ReturnUsers();
```

Comment: `[OperationContract(IsOneWay = "true")] List<tblUserInfo> ReturnUsers();` won't work either, as one-way methods cannot have a return type.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a little misleading. Indeed, you should not declare the operation contract in the class - but you have already declared it in the interface.

However, if you try to declare it (as a one-way operation, one that the client calls and doesn't get any response) in the interface, you'll have another error - one-way methods can only be declared in methods that don't return anything (i.e., that "return" `void`).